# Error 2019 when declaring a template class constructor in Visual C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

My method constructor accepts a template parameter value and I know templates can be used in the implementation file (.cpp) by preceding each method with

```
template<class T>;
classname<T>::memberfunction(){
}
```

When i put the definition of my constructor together with the class definition, the error doesn't show. For learning purposes, i want to put the implementation on a seperate file .cpp

I'm getting this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl
>   myclass::myclass(int)" (??0?$myclass@H@@QEAA@H@Z) referenced
>   in function
>   main  ConsoleTestProject  C:\Users\Winux\Desktop\MINE\Project\Lab1\ConsoleTestSolution\ConsoleTestProject\ConsoleTestProject.obj  1

How do you properly put the implementation in the cpp file?

I saw suggested similar questions but not specific to my error and problem.
Here's a simple code on how to recreate the bug. For simplicity, i did not include the getter and setter of the field.

myclass.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef myclass_h
#define myclass_h

template <class Type>
class myclass
{
private:
    Type value;

public:
    myclass(Type value);
};
#endif
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

template <class Type>
tree<Type>::myclass(Type value)
{
    this->value = value;
}
```

mysample.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myclass.h"

int main()
{
    myclass <int> aclass(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added in my question that i'm not asking the same duplicate question. In fact, i believe the opposite.

Comment: You may believe it, but if the answer is "put it in the header because ..." then it is certainly true that **This question already has an answer here:**.

Comment: Why do you think it's not the same as the duplicate? Duplicate explains exactly your error. TL;DR of the dupe: **You cannot put definition of template functions in source file**, because compiler needs to see the full definition of template wherever it's used.

Comment: Notes: You may find the text version of the error messages in the Output Tab easier to wrangle into Stack overflow questions. Plus sometimes they cntain extra information. Very handy. If you know what the template will be used with, you can play around with [explicit template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Comment: Nope, as i've mentioned, i'm looking for answers that puts the implementation of a template in the .cpp file.

Comment: It's also explained in the duplicate question, but it may not be what you're looking for. If you put implementation in cpp file, you have to `#include` that file as well. Or use *explicit template specialization*, as linked above by user4581301, but this limits your `template` only to classes you explicitly mention in a cpp file.

Comment: That's what i did, I included the header of that template class definition. check my sample code.

Comment: Please, read the answers in the duplicate. They explain the matter much better than we can do in comments. If you put definition of template fuction in a cpp file, you have to include **the cpp file as well**. Compiler **has to** see the full definition of template functions to compile code.

Comment: Sadly sometimes the answer to a question is, "You can't do it." At least not for the general case. The duplicate link explains why.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, surprisingly, your suggestion "include the cpp file as well" worked! but including the .cpp at the end of the header as suggested in the duplicate question link doesn't. I didn't saw any explanation why this works. thanks anyway

Comment: That works for now. But watch what happens later when the cpp file gets more complicated and the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) kicks in.

Comment: @user4581301 i know what you mean, and the only solution is to put everything together in the header when its a template method. I think this is a not so clean c++ semantics and does not follow common principles seperating complex definitions in another file. I hope this can be improved to be more consistent to c++ programming principles